# svn: Server doesn't support setting arbitrary revision properties during commit

Tags: svn

When trying to execute the following svn command:

`svn commit --with-revprop "original-author=Jan Jansen <jan@example.com>"`

I receive the following message:

`svn: Commit failed (details follow):`

`svn: Server doesn't support setting arbitrary revision properties during commit`

I did the test on two different clients, so my feeling is that it isn't client related. However, I didn't find in any option offered for the SVN server something that could help.

Does someone have any idea where this issue could come from ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: A quick grasp at the Subversion book doesn't mention this is disabled by default. I have the impression that it's a custom hook. Do you have access to the repository files? ... or the repository admin?

Comment: I have access to everything but I'm no SVN expert. If there is such a hook, any idea where to find it ?

Comment: Hooks can be found in the `hooks` directory inside your repository (not your working copy but the repository files). But Ben's answer looks correct. Anything older than 1.5 is definitively worth an upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using Subversion over a `svn://` or `svn+ssh://` URL.  The `svnserve` server supporting your repository is too old to support the `--with-revprop` option to commit.    The option was added with 1.5 so you'll need to upgrade the server to something newer than 1.5.  Given that 1.5 and 1.6 are no longer support by the Apache Subversion project, I'd recommend that you upgrade to 1.7 or 1.8.

Note that while revision properties are restricted from being modified after commit with a `pre-revprop-change` hook (and by default can't be changed without such a hook being added) they are not restricted from being set at commit time unless the `pre-commit` hook script does so (which it will not do so by default).  This is documented in [the 1.5 release notes](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.5.html#revprops-compatibility).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to upgrade the `svnserve` server.